# RHEL 5 server hang, which logs

Tags: logging, rhel5

I have a server which is hanging more times than I would like, are there any logs in particular that would be worth examining to determine the reason?

`/var/log/messages` has nothing of note `/var/log/dmesg` is also not useful.

The machine hangs in that there is no response from a network ping, nothing on the console screen but it still has power. You have to press and hold the off button to turn it off before it will turn on.

The main service is `samba` (it is the domain controller), also `pptp`, `dhcp` and `bind`.

It seems it was a problem with the power supply.  Thanks for spending the time answering and for the suggestion.

Comment: What services are you running? Is there any interesting in `dmesg` output (it's different from `/var/log/dmesg`). Do you have physical access to this server?

Comment: @quanta I have access to the machine, there is nothing unusual from dmesg, certainly nothing **fail** ling.

Comment: Could you please show us some output from `top` command (or `atop`, `htop`) sort by CPU usage, disk I/O, memory, ...

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. Do you have hardware monitoring tools installed? Otherwise, make sure you have applied all CentOS updates and updated all firmware.

Comment: You might try using the Magic Sysreq keys to get a dump or some more data when it hangs.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Comment: No one can answer this question without some more diagnoses. If nothing getting written to logs it may suggest disk problems. If smartctl is not installed, then install it when next comes up and test disks. Random crashes with nothing being logged is a symptom of many causes. Last time I had random crashes turned out to be RAM, saw that RAM went from 6B to 4GB in `free` which helped me find the fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue on a CentOS5 box. Try to update your network drivers (if you have a Realtek 8168 based NIC):

```
rpm -Uvh http://elrepo.org/elrepo-release-5-3.el5.elrepo.noarch.rpm
yum install kmod-r8168
```

And then reboot your machine.

Comment: How do you know the original poster use this driver?

Comment: I didn't (my bad). I changed my post to explain it's only for Realtek 8168 based NICs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more specific about the hangs?  Is the machine responsive from the console but loses network access?  Any console logs or kernel panic messages?   The latter would be on the screen, but possibly not in any log files.

Comment: added description of the hang